# Put me off on/in your list?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Let's say you have just firmly decided not to take part of the upcoming interview, could you say:

> "I am very sorry, I am no longer interested in joining, could you please put me off **on/in** your list on the upcoming interview."

Which preposition is correct?

Comment: You might want to take a closer look at the relevant verb:  "Put me on[to] the list" differs from "take me off [of] the list" or "keep me off [of] the list".  Also, any such list is more likely a list *for* the upcoming interview.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Usage**

In general, you "put something on a list" and "take something off a list". In addition, lists are generally "of" something (when describing what's on the list) or "for" something (when describing the purpose of the list). In this case, the preposition "for" is more appropriate. As a result, I would express your sentence in the following way:

> I am very sorry. I am no longer interested in joining. Could you please take me off your list for the upcoming interview?

(Also note the use of periods to separate entire sentences, rather than commas.)

**Declining Interviews**

This note is probably too direct in what ought to be a somewhat delicate situation. Turning down an interview after it's been offered can potentially burn bridges.

I'd suggest saying the same thing without saying, "I am no longer interested in joining." It could imply you've changed your mind about the company and never want to be work there, even in the future.

I'd word your note in the following way (or something similar):

> Thank you very much for considering me for this position. However, I would like to withdraw my application at this time. I sincerely appreciate your time and attention.